How to mock aiohttp.client.ClientSession.get async context manager with multiple different responses
To follow up on this question
For one API request, I was able to get this answer working for 1 API request using MagicMock below:
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_download():
    mock = aiohttp.ClientSession
    mock.get = MagicMock()
    mock.get.return_value.__aenter__.return_value.status = 200
    mock.get.return_value.__aenter__.return_value.text.return_value = 'test content'

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://test.com') as response:
            assert response.text() == 'test content'

How can I return multiple responses? For example, first API request returns 200, second API request returns 400.
I have tried many approaches and nothing has worked so far, including aioresponses library. Any help would be much appreciated
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_download():
    mock = aiohttp.ClientSession
    mock.get = MagicMock()
    # first API request
    mock.get.return_value.__aenter__.return_value.status = 200
    mock.get.return_value.__aenter__.return_value.text.return_value = 'test content'
    # second API request
    mock.get.return_value.__aenter__.return_value.status = 400
    mock.get.return_value.__aenter__.return_value.text.return_value = 'bad test content'
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://test.com') as response:
            assert response.text() == 'test content'


Probably using an iterable as the side_effect: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#calling

I tried side_effect without success. Maybe I was missing something small

Add your new attempt to the question?
